# Почему после добавление функции выдает ошибку?

Tags: php, sql

после того как добавил функцию страница перестала открываться вот код :

```
<?php
    include_once("bd.php");

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(empty($_POST['name']))  {
            echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Введите логин!"> Введите логин! </font>';
        } 

        elseif(empty($_POST['discord'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Введите дискорд !"> Введите пароль!</font>';
        }       
        /////1
        elseif(empty($_POST['player1-name'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Введите p1 !"> Введите p1</font>';
        }
            elseif(empty($_POST['player1-url'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Введите s1 !"> Введите s1!</font>';
        }
        /////2
                elseif(empty($_POST['player2-name'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Введите p2 !"> Введите p2</font>';
        }
            elseif(empty($_POST['player2-url'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Введите s2 !"> Введите s2</font>';
        }
        /*
                elseif(empty($_POST['player3-name'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Введите p3 !"> Введите p3</font>';
        }
            elseif(empty($_POST['player3-url'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Введите s3 !"> Введите s3</font>';
        }
        /////
                elseif(empty($_POST['player4-name'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Введите p4 !"> Введите p4</font>';
        }
            elseif(empty($_POST['player4-url'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Введите s4 !"> Введите s4</font>';
        }
        /////
                elseif(empty($_POST['player5-name'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Введите p5 !"> Введите p5</font>';
        }
            elseif(empty($_POST['player5-url'])) {
            echo '<br><font color="red"><img border="0" src="error.gif" align="middle" alt="Введите s5 !"> Введите s5</font>';
        }
        */////


        else{
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $discord = $_POST['discord'];

            $player1_name = $_POST['player1-name'];
            $player2_name = $_POST['player2-name'];
            $player3_name = $_POST['player3-name'];
            $player4_name = $_POST['player4-name'];
            $player5_name = $_POST['player5-name'];
$player1_url= $_POST['player1-url'];
$player2_url= $_POST['player2-url'];
$player3_url= $_POST['player3-url'];
$player4_url= $_POST['player4-url'];
$player5_url= $_POST['player5-url'];
             ///


///



                    $query = "INSERT INTO teams (team, discord,             p1,              s1,             p2,            s2,         p3,         s3,         p4,         s4,         p5,     s5 )
                                        VALUES ('$name', '$discord', '$player1_name', '$player1_url', '$player2_name', '$player2_url','$player3_name', '$player3_url','$player4_name', '$player4_url','$player5_name', '$player5_url')";
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
                    echo '<font color="green"><img border="0" src="ok.gif" align="middle" alt="Вы успешно зарегистрировались!"> Вы успешно зарегистрировались!</font><br><a href="../index.php">На главную</a>';




        }
    }
$ava1=ava($player1_url);
function ava($str){

$chars = ['/'];
$token='0BB94CE8C421C172D6C27F190AE1F1CA';
if (strpos($str, 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/') !== false){

    $str = substr($str, stripos($str, "profiles/")+9);
     $str = str_replace($chars,'', $str);



$img = @simplexml_load_file(sprintf("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=0BB94CE8C421C172D6C27F190AE1F1CA&steamids=".$str."&format=xml"));

return $img->players->player->avatarfull;
}else{
$str = substr($str, stripos($str, "/id/")+3);
 $str = str_replace($chars, '', $str);
 $xmlstr = @simplexml_load_file(sprintf("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key=%s&format=xml&vanityurl=%s", $token, $str));

$id=$xmlstr->steamid;
$img = @simplexml_load_file(sprintf("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=0BB94CE8C421C172D6C27F190AE1F1CA&steamids=".$id."&format=xml"));
return $img->players->player->avatarfull;


    }
}
    }
```

Comment: включите отображение ошибок

Comment: ужасный код....

Comment: В конце лишняя закрывающая фигурная скобка.

Comment: не помогло (убрал скобку)

Comment: Это Ваш полный код? Здесь в конце лишняя закрывающая фигурная скобка как сказал Александр. Но и попробуйте изменить `$chars = ['/'];` на `$chars = array('/');` @MininDm